# python data structure: list of dict to one dict

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have a data structure. It looks as follows:

```
data = [[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2A', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3A', 'name': 'grandChild-A', 'steps': 2}],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2A', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3B', 'name': 'grandChild-B', 'steps': 2}],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2B', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3A', 'name': 'grandChild-C', 'steps': 2}],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2B', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3B', 'name': 'grandChild-D', 'steps': 2}],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2B', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3C', 'name': 'grandChild-E', 'steps': 2},
 {'id': '4A', 'name': 'final', 'steps': 3}
 ],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 ]
]
```

How my expected output is

### expected output

```
output = {
    "1" : {
        "2A": {
            "3A": "grandChild-A",
            "3B": "grandChild-B"

        },
        "2B": {
            "3A": "grandChild-C",
            "3B": "grandChild-D",
            "3C": {
                "4A": "final"
            }

        },
        "2":"child"

    }
}
```

How can I do that? I wanted to use the enumerator, But I always everything inside 1. 
Thanks in advance

Update:

I have tried the following code:

```
parent = data[0][0]["id"]
dict_new = {}
dict_new[parent] = {}

for e in data:
    for idx, item in enumerate(e):
        display(item)
        if idx>0:
            dict_new[parent][e[idx]["id"]] = e[idx]["name"]
```

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am updating my code. please dont close it. I really need help

Comment: it has been updated @quamrana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
d = {}
root = d
for L in data:
    d = root
    for M in L[:-1]:
        d = d.setdefault(M["id"], {})
    d[L[-1]["id"]] = L[-1]['name']
```

The idea is to follow each list to build a tree (thus `d.setdefault(M["id"], {})`. The leaf is handled differently, because it has to be the value of 'name'.

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(root)
```

Output:

```
{'1': {'2': 'child',
       '2A': {'3A': 'grandChild-A', '3B': 'grandChild-B'},
       '2B': {'3A': 'grandChild-C',
              '3B': 'grandChild-D',
              '3C': {'4A': 'final'}}}}
```

---

The solution above won't work for the following input:

```
data = [[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2B', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1}]],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2B', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3A', 'name': 'grandChild-C', 'steps': 2}]]
```

Iterating over the second list will try to add a new element `3A -> grandChild-C` to the `d['1']['2B']` dict. But `d['1']['2B']` *is not* a dict but the `'child'` string here, because of the first list.

When we iterate over the elements, we check if the key is already mapped and otherwise create a new dict (that's the `setdefault` job). We can also check if the key was mapped to a `str`, and if that's the case, replace the string by a fresh new dict:

```
...
for M in L[:-1]:
    if M["id"] not in d or isinstance(d[M["id"]], str):
        d[M["id"]] = {}
    d = d[M["id"]]
...
```

Output:

```
{'1': {'2B': {'3A': 'grandChild-C'}}}
```

Comment: Why use `setdefault()` over `collections.defaultdict` ?

Comment: @AMC. It's a matter of personal taste: I prefer to avoid the magic of `defaultdict`, but you are right: the code may be cleaner with a `defaultdict` and `d = d[M["id"]]`.

Comment: @jferard I'm not familiar with its implementation, which magic are you referring to?

Comment: @jferard when I trying it out with different data with the same structure, I am getting following error `'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @itsMe Can you provide additional data? It seems that `d` becomes a `str` at some point, but I don't see how.

Comment: Indeed, after some iteration it becomes strings

Comment: @itsMe: it's possible if one list begins like a previous one but has more elements. Then the last element of the first list is not a dict, but a string (the name) and can't be extended in the second list. What should be the behavior in this case?

Comment: for that case, the id should be taken and new nested dict should be created with the ID. like the situation with 3C

Comment: @itsMe Can't fix it tonight, but I'll update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will wait for your answer

Comment: @itsMe Is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your data: (missing comma)

```
data = [[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2A', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3A', 'name': 'grandChild-A', 'steps': 2}],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2A', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3B', 'name': 'grandChild-B', 'steps': 2}],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2B', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3A', 'name': 'grandChild-C', 'steps': 2}],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2B', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3B', 'name': 'grandChild-D', 'steps': 2}],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2B', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 {'id': '3C', 'name': 'grandChild-E', 'steps': 2},
 {'id': '4A', 'name': 'final', 'steps': 3}
 ],

[{'id': '1', 'name': 'parent', 'steps': 0},
 {'id': '2', 'name': 'child', 'steps': 1},
 ]
]
```

And I came up with this code:

```
output = {}
#print(data)

for lis in data:
    o = output
    ln = len(lis) - 1
    for idx,d in enumerate(lis):
        id = d['id']
        if idx == ln:
            o[id] = d['name']
        else:
            if id not in o:
                o[id] = {}
            o = o[id]

print('Result:')
print(output)
```

Comment: when I trying it out with different data with the same structure, I am getting following error 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Perhaps you need to ask a new question. Refer back to this question, show your new data and quote the code from the accepted answer and also the full error Traceback.